# Silverlight - animate element within control's template

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I'm looking at the [ComboBox template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

I have a `StoryBoard` that I'm creating in code, and I want to animate something in the `ComboBox` with it. It works fine if I just want to do a property, like "Background", but what is the right way to animate a template part like, for instance, the `Rectangle` named `Highlight`?

I've tried setting the property path to `(ComboBox).(Highlight).(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidBrush.Color)` but that gives me an error saying it can't resolve that on the given object.

edit: It looks like WPF has some overloads on StoryBoard.Begin() that make this easy, but I don't see anything like that for Silverlight 4

edit2: and to clarify, I'm trying to do this on a default Silverlight ControlTemplate, not one I'm defining myself (I'd like to avoid copying that template into my codebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the [`OnApplyTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate%28VS.95%29.aspx) method and see if you can attach the storyboard programmatically to the actual template part at that time. You use [`GetTemplateChild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.gettemplatechild%28VS.95%29.aspx) to retrieve the template parts.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I appreciate your answer, but I'm not really sure how that helps me. 

In `OnApplyTemplate`, how would you suggest I try to access template parts?

Comment: You can request them by name. If you look in the template (or the docs) each part has a name - you can retrieve the elements by those names. See my edit.

Comment: Yep, I just figured that out after making my comment. Unfortunately this means I have to subclass my combobox, and it turns out that which I'm looking for is actually a part of the 'togglebutton' in the combobox, which opens up a whole other can of worms, but I guess that's my answer. Thanks Jeff!

Comment: @ArmedMonkey: No problem. I've been in the same boat and almost always, I've had to end up copying the entire template to insert the extra stuff I need. It's a little painful but worth it to get it all working right.